# Cisco IronPort WSA - how to block non corporate Google mail pages

Tags: cisco, g-suite, gmail, ironport

this was just a thought and I wondered if anyone else had managed to do it or thought about it.

We use Google apps for Business and to avoid any issues, we have whitelisted all of Google's IP ranges on our Cisco Ironport.
However, some of our users abuse this and spend all day in their own Google mail account.
Is it possible to block non corporate Gmail URL's to prevent them from logging in to their own accounts?

I would really like to hear if anyone else has managed to do this or given it any thought. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Should be pretty easy according to https://support.google.com/a/answer/1668854?hl=en (sorry do not know if iron port supports it)

Comment: Check http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/security/cloud-web-security/configure-cws-00.pdf , as I have difficulty to find ironport documentation, it relate to CWS, so let me know if the doc fit your appliance menu

Comment: Hi thanks for the input guys. All Google traffic does go through our proxy (the IronPort) but I fail to see where I can input the X headers mentioned in both of these documents. I may be overlooking something so I will continue to search and let you know if I find anything.